# Express.js angular.js

Tags: angularjs, express

> ```
> angular.module('App').factory('Blogs', ['$resource', function($resource) {
>     return $resource('/api/blog/:blogId/:catId/:search/:pagenum' , {
>              blog: '@blogId',
>                   page: "@pageController",
>                   pagenum: '@pagenum'
>       },
>       {
>             Page: {
>                   params: {
>                     pageController: "page"
>                   }
>                 },
>             Cat: {
>                   params: {
>                     catController: "cat",
>                     catId: 'catId'
>                   }
>               }
>       });
> }]);
> ```

I have made the above service in angularjs , can i access the page method defined in it in my controller i.e can i call Blogs.Page/Blogs.Cat in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can use it like this:

```
function PageController($scope, Blogs){
 Blogs.Page(function(response){
   $scope.pages = response;
 });
}
```

Also can be params:

```
function PageController($scope, Blogs){
 Blogs.Page({ id: 3}, function(response){
   $scope.pages = response;
 });
}
```

I've recommended to you see: [Restangular repo](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), How use: [video from developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGrpnt2VQ3s)